# Possible Copycat site

Tags: discussion, clone

I came across this site today - http://www.debugging.com/

It is remarkably similar to SO.  It doesn't appear to be pulling any information from SO but I guess I wanted to highlight it.

The best part is in the About section:

> Debugging strives to be the best Programming Q & A community, period.

Talk about missing the boat! I think he may be a touch late on that one.

Does someone need to send the Ninjas round?

Comment: Wow that site looks *really* bad at least in Chrome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as they're not stealing content, I don't think they're actually doing anything wrong..

They're also already known to be a copycat site, they are listed in the [SO Clones](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2267/stack-overflow-clones/3237#3237) question.

Answer (score 1):

I can tell you that it does not take any content from SO.  Though it appears to look similar on the surface, it is not.  I used to be an active member of that community.  Considering it only had a handful of knowledgeable active members, it was slow.  The functionality of the site in general was lacking too.  When I found SO, that's when I move here.

It was formerly CSharpFriends.com until the owner redesigned the UI and migrated over to the new site.  IIRC, it was a school project went live.  Don't be fooled by the dates on the old site.  It predates SO starting up in 2003-2004.

Comment: Tags, the UI design, that pre-date SO too? :)

Comment: @Nick: From the redesign, no.  SO definitely influenced the new design.  The old site resembled PHPBB (or other similar forum software).  As I understand it, it was all a learning experience building up both sites.  Naturally it would be influenced by current popular sites.  But all the content comes from real people (unfortunately, a lot looking for homework help).